# C++ static member, a little confused here

Tags: c++

```
    //static member in classes
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CDummy {
public:
    static int n;
    CDummy() {n++;};
    ~CDummy(){n--;};
};

int CDummy::n =0;

int main(){
    CDummy a;
    CDummy b[5];
    CDummy *c = new CDummy;
    cout << a.n << endl;
    delete c;
    cout << CDummy::n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is  7, 6.
Can anybody explain it for me?
and I don't understand this "CDummy b[5];". People never use syntax like this in C, right? what is this here?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you make sure you have [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: if this is a homework assignment or exercise it probably should be tagged as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CDummy b[5];
```

This declares an array of five `CDummy` objects.  It ends up calling the `CDummy` default constructor five times (once for each object in the array).

You create seven `CDummy` objects:  `a`, five in the array `b`, and the one pointed to by `c`.  `n` then has a value of `7`.  Then you destroy one `CDummy` object (the one pointed to by `c`) and `n` has a value of `6`.  The remaining six `CDummy` objects are destroyed when they go out of scope when the `main` function returns.

Answer (score 1):

`CDummy b[5]` is an array of five `CDummy` objects. `CDummy a` is simply a single instance of `CDummy`, and so is `CDummy c`.

Every time a `CDummy` is created, the constructor is called.

Let's add that up: `5 + 1 + 1 = 7`. That's why `n` was initially `7`. When `c` was deleted, `n--` was executed, and `n` became `6`.

Comment: Thank you. I got it...so much time not touch C++/ so stupid me...thanks

Comment: C++ becomes scarier to me the more I look at it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

static on this situation mean that the variable n is the same for all instances of CDummy, in your case a, b and c (after you allocate the object using new) all share the same n. Thats why you see this value.

CDummy b[5] -> this declares an array of CDummy, on this case 5 CDummys.

Answer (score 0):

`CDummy b[5]` is just an array of 5 CDummy objects.

A static member means there is only one instance of that member no matter how many instances are made of the class.

The class simply increments n from the constructor whenever a new instance is initialized, and decrements n from the destructor whenever the instance is destroyed. It's basically tracking how many instances of this class are currently active.

Answer (score 0):

`n` is a static member variable in class `CDummy`. n is associated with all objects of the class rather than each object instance of the class.
`n` is incremented as each object instance gets created and decremented as each object instance is destroyed.
In the main function we create object a (n=1), followed by array of objects b of size 5 (n=6) followed by pointer to object c (n=7). So the first `cout` statement output 7. As object pointed to by c is destroyed n is decremented to 6. 
So the second `cout` statement outputs 6.
Please refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1b5y48f.aspx) for details on static members in a class